# Android: Trying to create a dialog within a AsyncTask<String object

Tags: android

I'm using a AsyncTask

I use parent to create the intent no errors.

The line to creat a dialog gives a 
parent cannot be resolved to a ye.
 new parent.AlertDialog.Builder(this)

The error I get is that parent does not exist, but I use parent in the same methed to call the intent

code block
     private class SendTextOperation extends AsyncTask {

```
      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {

        //Update UI here

      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Talk to server here to avoid Ui hanging 
          rt=TalkToServer("http://besttechsolutions.biz/projects/bookclub/login.php");
          return(rt);
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  


          if (rt.contains("ok")) 
          {

              Intent i = new Intent(parent, cChat.class);
                startActivity(i);
          }
          else
          {

                 new parent.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Game Over")
                .setMessage("Your time is up, You saved " 
                        +" Million  more people!!")
                .setNeutralButton("Try Again",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int i)
                    {

                    }} ).show();    

          }
      }

}
```

Comment: try `new AlertDialog.Builder(parent)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing `AlertDialog` from non Activity you will need to pass Current Activity Context to non Activity class in your case to `SendTextOperation` class.

Create an `Constructor` for `SendTextOperation` as :

```
public class SendTextOperation extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
Context context;
    public SendTextOperation(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {

        //Update UI here

      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Talk to server here to avoid Ui hanging 
          rt=TalkToServer("http://besttechsolutions.biz/projects/bookclub/login.php");
          return(rt);
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {  


          if (rt.contains("ok")) 
          {

              Intent i = new Intent(context, cChat.class);
                startActivity(i);
          }
          else
          {

                 new context.AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Game Over")
                .setMessage("Your time is up, You saved " 
                        +" Million  more people!!")
                .setNeutralButton("Try Again",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int i)
                    {

                    }} ).show();    

          }
      }

}
```

and start `SendTextOperation`  `AsyncTask` as :

```
SendTextOperation sendtxtasyncTask = new SendTextOperation(CurrentActivity.this);
sendtxtasyncTask.execute("");
```

Comment: Or if AsyncTask is an inner non-static class of Activity, then you can just initialize AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)

Comment: plz don't upvote my answer because i have a `red hat` . then up-votes not effects my points

Comment: I upvoted because the answer is correct enough. Did'nt even looked at your rep.

Comment: @DoctororDrive : you are right but this answer work in both case

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have that class declared inside a class named MyActivity
Then use instead of this, MyActivity.this when creating the Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be calling it like this:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
            builder.setMessage(_context.getString(R.string.error) + ": " + _errorMessage)
                .setTitle(_context.getString(R.string.loginError))
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton(_context.getString(R.string.ok), null);

            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

(My own sample code)

It looks like your error is trying to do `parent.AlertDialog.Builder(this)`, where you need to use `new AlertDialog.Builder(parent)`, if parent is your context.